# Number of ways to distribute all n non-unique objects into k buckets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I will try to model this using collections of integers.

Let's say that we have the following collection
[1,1,1,2,2,3] and a number $k=3$ that indicates how many buckets we want.
$n \mod k = 0$ always.
All the buckets must contain the same amount of elements, the order of the elements inside the buckets is not important.

How can we count (we are not specifically interested in how they are composed) the possible combinations?
From the example above we want to get the number $z$ below.

K1=[1, 1] K2=[1, 2] K3=[2, 3]

K1=[1, 1] K2=[2, 3] K3=[1, 2]

K1=[2, 3] K2=[1, 2] K3=[1, 1]

K1=[1, 2] K2=[1, 1] K3=[2, 3]

K1=[1, 2] K2=[2, 3] K3=[1, 1]

K1=[2, 3] K2=[1, 1] K3=[1, 2]

K1=[1, 1] K2=[1, 3] K3=[2, 2]

K1=[1, 1] K2=[2, 2] K3=[1, 3]

K1=[1, 3] K2=[1, 1] K3=[2, 2]

K1=[1, 3] K2=[2, 2] K3=[1, 1]

K1=[2, 2] K2=[1, 3] K3=[1, 1]

K1=[2, 2] K2=[1, 1] K3=[1, 3]

K1=[1, 2] K2=[1, 2] K3=[1, 3]

K1=[1, 2] K2=[1, 3] K3=[1, 2]

K1=[1, 3] K2=[1, 2] K3=[1, 2]

z=15

While for the collection [1,1,2] z=3
because we can only have :

K1=[1] K2=[1] K3=[2]

K1=[1] K2=[2] K3=[1]

K1=[2] K2=[1] K3=[1]

Any ideas on how to calculate $z$? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: hint: ordering of the buckets seems important how many orders are there ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the rules.  In the first case, why can't I have $K_1=[1,2]$, $K_2=[1,2]$, $K_3=[1,3]$?

Comment: I thought I did but they are asking about combinations, but seeming to use permutations in there somewhere as well because  otherwise half ( more) of those 12 given can be eliminated as the same.

Comment: (n choose n/k) + [(n-n/k) choose n/k] + [(n-2n/k) choose n/k]  + ...

Comment: @lulu well spotted, you are right, editing the question. Sorry about that!

Comment: @uwnojpjm makes sense but if I have [1,1,1,1] and k=2 the result would be z=7 

$_4 C _2 + _2 C _2 $ 
but it's wrong because
K1= [1,1] K2=[1,1]
is the only valid unique combination

Comment: @AMeoni, then that with subtraction.

Comment: Subtract the non-unique repeats.

Comment: @uwnojpjm right, but how do I generalise that? It seems that in this case I should subtract $_4 C _2$ but why?

Comment: It's gonna be something like $f(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-i(n/k)}{n/k} - \text{repeats}$

Comment: I may have found something: $f(n,k)=\binom{n}{2\frac{n}{k}}$.

Comment: I am still struggling in trying to get rid of the repeats. It seems that the number of duplicate elements generates repeated combinations when it's greater than $n/k$. I cannot rationalize this into a formula or a series of steps at least.

Comment: @AMeoni, have you tried my `n choose 2n/k` solution?

Comment: @uwnojpjm I tried but I don't know how to apply that in a generic way

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?